# I have this php code how can i make it generate random length from 1 to 16

Tags: php

I have this php code how can i make it generate random from 1 to 10

```
$seed = str_split('aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ123456789');
$rand = array_rand($seed, 16);
$convert = array_map(function($n){
    global $seed;
    return $seed[$n];
},$rand);

$var1 = implode('',$convert);
```

so need this one to show random not 16 like its there but random length from 1 to 16 each time user comes.

Comment: Replace 16 with 10?

Comment: i mean this code shows only 16 random letters so i need this to change this 16 to random all times not fixed 16

Comment: any reason you picked that seed? There is 1 liners which can do this

Comment: no please share with me one if you have another, just to do the job to change all times

Comment: Wrap it in a function and pass a parameter - 1,2,10,16 whatever.

Comment: I'm not seeing what the problem is.  The current code will produce a different value for `$var1` every time it is executed.

Comment: yes but im asking to show random all times as its doing it but the other change i need no 16 length but random length

Comment: So you're familiar with `array_rand()`, but not [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet without using `map`

```
function generateRandString($length = 10) {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $charsLength = strlen($chars);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $chars[rand(0, $charsLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get n number of items from the array.
Including a [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) inside the array slice means it returns a random length between 1 and 10 characters.

```
$seed = str_split('aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ123456789');

shuffle($seed);
echo implode("", array_slice($seed,0,rand(1,10)));
```

https://3v4l.org/RX9XO

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve what you want without rewriting all your code is to replace:

```
$rand = array_rand($seed, 16);
```

with

```
$rand = array(array_rand($seed, mt_rand(1,10)));
```

That will simply pass a different length parameter to `array_rand()` on each run

Comment: true. But easily fixable by doing `$rand = array(array_rand($seed, mt_rand(1,10)));` I forgot to add that part, thanks for noticing

Comment: Never said it couldn't be fixed, just that the way you had it was problematic.